# How to draw histogram with same bins width for unequally spaced bins in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to draw a histogram with multiple data series in matplotlib.

I have unequally spaced bins, however I want that each bin get the same width. So I used attribute `width` in this way:

```
aa = [0,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,9]
plt.hist([aa, aa], bins=[0,3,9], width=0.2)
```

The result is this:

[image: Histogram with unequally spaced bins]

How can I get rid of the margin between two correspondent bins of the two series? I.e. how can I group for each bin the bars of the different series?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a solution can be to compute the histogram by numpy and plot the bars individually by hand:

```
aa1 = [0,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,9]
aa2 = [0,1,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,9]
bins = [0,3,9]
height = [np.histogram( xs, bins=bins)[0] for xs in [aa1, aa2]]
left, n = np.arange(len(bins)-1), len(height)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
color_cycle = ax._get_lines.color_cycle

for j, h in enumerate(height):
    ax.bar(left + j / n, h, width=1.0/n, color=next(color_cycle))

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(bins)))
ax.set_xticklabels(map(str, bins))
```

[image: hist]

Comment: Nice solution.. I wait just a little to know if there is something builtin. +1 for now

Comment: `width` can be an array.  I read the question as wanting the bars to be the correct width for the bin width....

Comment: As there are not other answer, I accept it. Please note that this solution works only in Python 3+, because of the implicit float division when calculating the offset in the `ax.bar()` call. Consider adding a `float(j)` cast to make it useful also for Python 2. Thanks

Comment: @unsel I guess you are right about float division; i ran this on python 2.7; but it worked for me because i always have `from __future__ import division` on top of my scripts.