# Forcing uniform bin display widths in a python histogram for non-uniform data binning

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a set of dates corresponding to publishing years for a few hundred books. The vast majority are 1800 to present. But a few (<10) are pre-1800 but widely scattered. What I want is to have my bins go like this:

[0,1600,1700,1800,1810,1820,...2000,2010,2020]

But for the displayed bins to all be the same number of pixels wide.

Here is my code so far:

```
import sys
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import math as m

def importData(fileName):

  dataArray=[]
  file=open(fileName,'rb')
  data = csv.reader(file,delimiter="\t")
  for row in data:
    dataArray.append(row[4])
  file.close()
  dataArray=np.array(dataArray).astype(int)
  return dataArray

dates = importData("tabulatedDates.dat")

binDivs=np.array([1600,1700]+range(1800,2021,10))

plt.hist(dates,bins=(binDivs),label=["Books"])

plt.xticks(binDivs,rotation=75)
plt.xlim([1600,2020])
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',bottom='off')

plt.grid(True,axis='y',which='both')
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Number of books published during this period")
plt.title("Published year of recommended books")

plt.show()
```

Here is the output, I want to make those annoying wide bins the same width as the rest of the bins but still represent 100 years

[image: First example]

Now I could use this code with the width variable set, but then I have a bunch of ugly white space which is just as problematic.

```
plt.hist(dates,bins=(binDivs),width=10,label=["Books"])
```

[image: Second example]

Comment: Why not just set the x-axis tick labels to be continuous?

Comment: As in [1600, 1610..., 1700, 1710...2010, 2020]

Comment: Seems to me both of those histograms are slightly misleading -- the first (worse) visually overstates the number of pre-1800 books, and the second strongly implies that they were all published in 1600 and 1700 exactly. I would try a line plot for 1600-1800 to show those books, and then the histogram to summarize the mass of data.

Comment: I disagree, the first version looks correct to me.   It says 'this many books are in this period'.  If you are worried about the area <-> number of books than change the y-axis to be book/year so that your integration comes out correct.

Comment: or maybe you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461355/how-to-draw-histogram-with-same-bins-width-for-unequally-spaced-bins-in-matplotl?rq=1.

Comment: @reptilicus If I made it continuous I would have huge areas of zero, especially since my oldest book is BC700.

Comment: @cphlewis I'm not sure what you mean by "line plot" in this context?  <br />
I agree that they are both misleading (or at least ugly).  
<br />
Edit: I did look at that question, but I was hoping there was a nicer solution. I could probably adapt that solution but I just feels like there should be a quick way.

Comment: @tcaswell The first version is technically correct, it just looks ugly. I'm not trying to integrate anything so I don't really care about the area. This is purely for visual presentation.

Comment: I was thinking of a dot for each actual book before 1800, plotted at its actual year of publication. (All of six, yes?) There would be a lot of whitespace but the x-axis would be consistent. I think it will only be unusually careful readers who deduce that the two big bins have different _denominators_ than the decade-bins, and since the sparse representation from the period seems like one of the interesting things about the plot, I'd hate to make it less obvious.

Comment: Oh! I just saw the comment about 700BC. Maybe you want a logarithmic x-axis? Though that will confuse people too.

Comment: I actually think that what you *want* to do would be the *most* misleading representation.  Deliberately futzing with an otherwise linear axis just makes for more confusion all around.

Comment: Maybe it's just that I'm used to that being done in physics where we will have a single bin with all the outliers summed up.  
I would of course point out the oddity in the figure caption.

Comment: Publication dates seem like survivors, not just outliers. (Is there a Data Visualization Stack Overflow?)